# To go in cycles

Tags: idioms, phrases

“If ever you wanted proof football goes in cycles, then surely it was the sight of Leicester being confounded by an opposition playing 4-4‑2” https://www.theguardian.com/football/2021/oct/30/leicester-arsenal-premier-league-match-report. I assume it’s trying to say that football is repetitive. I did not find any result when I searched through dictionaries, so I am a little doubtful about it, although I checked a few dictionaries to see all definitions for “go”.

Answer (score 2):

It means "repetitive"  but on longer timescale that you seem to imagine.

For example people sometime say "Life goes in cycles": First you are a baby, you need someone to dress and feed you.  Then you are an adult and you are independent.  Then you are old and you need someone to dress and feed you again.  Life has gone in a cycle.

Or "School goes in cycles"  Each year you start out keen to learn, then you struggle through the terms, then you are tested. And when the new school year starts again you are keen to learn again.

"Football goes in cycles"  In the 1950s Chelsea were a top division club,  then in the 1970s and 1980s they got less strong and were demoted to the second division,  then in the 1990s and 2000s they became a top club again. Perhaps the cycle will repeat.

Here it means that there was strategy that worked long in the past (4-4-2 structure) but recently this strategy hasn't confounded Leicester. But now the cycle is repeating and Leicester are again confounded by a 4-4-2 defence.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect explanation. I usually look through multiple senses of a key word in (here, go) such phrases to find a sensible meaning. It would be great if you could tell me which sense of “go” (according to Merriam Webster sense number) is used here.

Comment: Either 1a "Proceed" (metaphorically)  or 3a "follow a certain procedure" or 10b "maintain a certain action"